# Data sheet for the dynamic viscosity of salt-water-glycerol solutions

Tags: viscosity

Does anyone know where I can get data for the dynamic viscosity of salt-water-glycerol solutions? Specifically 80% glycerol and 20% salt water by mass at 19.2 degrees celsius. Salt concentrations vary between 0 and ~1 mol dm^-3. Anything close is also appreciated. If this is too specific for data sheets and textbooks, are there simple equations or simpler data sheets that I could use to approximate the values I need? If you're wondering, I need results of papers to back up my lab results. Thanks.

Comment: As a start in the CRC handbook of Chemistry & Physics, at 25 C and 80% mass percent glycerol the viscosity of glycerol water is given as 45.9 cp.

Comment: Effect of the salt on viscosity is hard to predict.